# Manage a big number of report file

Tags: reports

The issue is the following:
I have a huge amount of report files (+10000) and I need to analyze them.

1. Even on SSD I got problem using filemanager to group and divide them ( maybe is a problem with nautilus ) ...
2. filename is not very meaning full so it is difficult to remember a particular log file.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Following code will:

1. rename each report on the base of its time creation (format ex. 10_50_01 it will be the new filename for a report created a 10:50:01)
2. Create a new folder (format ex. May-20-2014) for each day and put all report for that day in it

   ```
   $pathBase = $MAGE_ROOT_FOLDER . '/var/report/';
   $files = glob($pathBase . '*');
   // sort by date
   usort($files, function ($a, $b) {
       return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
   });

   foreach ($files as $i => $f) {
      $filename = pathinfo($f, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
      $timeStamp = filemtime($f);
      $toDir = date("F-d-Y", $timeStamp) . '/';
      $newDateName = date("H-i-s", $timeStamp);

      echo $i . $filename . ' - ' . $newDateName . ' -> ' . $toDir . '<br/>';

      if (!is_dir($pathBase . $toDir)) {
          echo 'Create Dir' . '<br/>';
          mkdir($pathBase . $toDir, 0777, true);
      }

     echo 'Rename and Move' . '<br/>';
     rename($f, $pathBase . $toDir . $newDateName);
   }
   ```